# Jasper Reports w/ Maven - How do I specify Java version to compile with?

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports

Is there any way I can specify which version of Java to use when compiling my .jrxml files with Jasper Reports in Maven (using jasperreports-maven-plugin)? I saw [this blog post](http://medievalcode.com/blog/2012/04/16/jasperreports---unsupported-majorminor-version-510/) saying claiming that Jasper uses the "*default virtual machine set in your computer*" and not "same version of the maven-compiler-plugin". **If I cannot change or guarantee the JAVA_HOME environment variable, how can I get Jasper to compile with Java6**?

Here is a snippet from my pom.xml:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-beta-2</version>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>compile</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
</plugins>
```

Looking on the [Codehaus docs](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jasperreports-maven-plugin/compile-reports-mojo.html), there is a  parameter you can use, but it doesn't say how to specify which Java version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MOJO-809) the folllowing parameters can help you:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler</compiler>
  ...
</configuration>
```

1.0-beta-2, however, does not have these properties, so the later version is necessary. You can either use a snapshot plugin version from [here](https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/codehaus/mojo/jasperreports-maven-plugin/1.0-beta-3-SNAPSHOT/), of build a plugin from source code yourself. As far as I can see, [plugin code from trunk](https://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/mojo/trunk/mojo/jasperreports-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/codehaus/mojo/jasperreports/JasperReportsMojo.java?r2=16122&r1=8082) supports these parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make some additional configurations:

- set eclipse:jdtcore as exclusion in jasperresports;

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.0</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
        <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

- set `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj` as plugin dependency;

jasperreports-maven-plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasperreports-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-beta-4-OPENNMS-20160912-1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/reports</outputDirectory>
                    <maven.compiler.source>${compileSource}</maven.compiler.source>
                    <maven.compiler.target>${compileSource}</maven.compiler.target>
                    <compiler>net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRJdtCompiler</compiler>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile-reports</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                        <version>4.4.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
                        <version>5.6.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
```

**Note:** the dependencies order of plugin `jasperreports-maven-plugin` was relevant for me (don't ask me why).